# Pinescript to generate buy/sell signal on multiple time frames simultaneously

Tags: pine-script

I need one pine script where the buy or signal gets generated on multiple time frames. e.g. I have a strategy which runs on 10 min timeframe  I want the final Buy/Sell signal to be generate only if they are generated on lower time frame like 1min, 2min, 3min and 5 min simultaneously.

Comment: Okay, cool. What's stopping you from writing one? You might want to take the [tour]: we help people with problems in _their_ code. We're not here to write code for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate `buy/sell` signal conditions from another chart scope (other TF) by using `request.security()` function and then, based of this calculations, calculate another buy/sell conditions for the current chart:

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html#request-security